# Why nullpointerexception when parsing xml in android application?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

we have a android application that works fine up to android 2.1, but when we try to  release it for android 2.2 we get a nullpointerexception. This happens when we're parsing a xml, on the following line of code:

```
((node) getText.item(0).getNodeValue();
```

help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

[`NullPointerException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) may be thrown under several different scenarios. From the documentation:

> Thrown when an application attempts to use `null` in a case where an object is required. These include:
>
> - Calling the instance method of a `null` object.
> - Accessing or modifying the field of a `null` object.
> - Taking the length of `null` as if it were an array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of `null` as if it were an array.
> - Throwing `null` as if it were a `Throwable` value.
>
> Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the `null` object.

As with any exception, you should carefully examine the stack trace to see if there's any useful information about why it was thrown. If indeed it is caused by illegally accessing a `null` reference as if it was a real object, then the general approach to debugging these kinds of problems is to to break up expressions like this:

```
// chained method invokations, can be hard to debug
var.method1().method2(arg).method3()
```

Into multiple statements like this:

```
// broken into multiple assignments
var1 = var.method1();
var2 = var1.method2();
var3 = var2.method3();
```

Now when a `NullPointerException` occurs, you'll know the exact part of the chain that throws it, namely which `var` is `null`.

Identifying the *where* part quickly narrows the search for the *why*. If `var` itself is `null`, then trace it back to previous assignments. If `varN` is `null`, then look up the documentation for `methodN()` to see under what circumstances can it return `null`.

If the `null` comes from a `get`-type operation on a container/mutable data structure, then the problem is no longer as neatly localized, and you'll have to figure out where the corresponding `set` happened. If `null` is never a legal value for this container, then perhaps it should perform the `null`-check during `set`: it's always better to cause failure earlier rather than later, because the source of the bug can be localized more easily.

#### Related questions

On debugging `NullPointerException`:

- [How to trace a NullPointerException in a chain of getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410890/how-to-trace-a-nullpointerexception-in-a-chain-of-getters)
- [Find out what variable is throwing a NullPointerException programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667908/find-out-what-variable-is-throwing-a-nullpointerexception-programatically)

On application-specific behavior for throwing `NullPointerException`:

- [IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter)
- [Is it okay to throw NullPointerException programatically ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322638/is-it-okay-to-throw-nullpointerexception-programatically)

On other `NullPointerException` scenarios instructive for learning:

- [Why does `String.valueOf(null)` throw a `NullPointerException`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131865/why-does-string-valueofnull-throw-a-nullpointerexception)
- [Why `null == 0` throws `NullPointerException` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352791/why-null-0-throws-nullpointerexception-in-java)
- [Why does `int num = Integer.getInteger("123")` throw `NullPointerException`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123349/why-does-int-num-integer-getinteger123-throw-nullpointerexception)

On `null` itself:

- [What is `null` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java/)
- [How to avoid `!= null` statements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/how-to-avoid-null-statements-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

That's a malformed code. Please correct. Then make sure you do not call any method on a `null` value.